# Error: Cannot find module 'routes' Require stack node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

Whenever I try to run my `express` server, I keep getting the same error from `node.js`

Here is my code:

```
import express, { Application, Request, Response } from "express";
import routes from "routes";

const app: Application = express();
app.use("/api", routes);
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.send("<h1>Hi api<h1>");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`app is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

And here is the error that I am getting:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'routes'
Require stack:
- E:\Work\Bedaya\api\src\index.ts
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename.sharedData.moduleResolveFilenameHook.installedValue [as _resolveFilename] (E:\Work\Bedaya\api\node_modules\@cspotcode\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:811:30)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Work\Bedaya\api\src\index.ts:2:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Module.m._compile (E:\Work\Bedaya\api\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1618:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (E:\Work\Bedaya\api\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1621:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'E:\\Work\\Bedaya\\api\\src\\index.ts' ]
```

When I tried changing `"routes"` to `"./routes"`, it gave me the same error but with another module as well.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'database'
Require stack:
- E:\Work\Bedaya\api\src\models\User.ts
- E:\Work\Bedaya\api\src\controllers\users.controller.ts
- E:\Work\Bedaya\api\src\routes\api\users.route.ts
- E:\Work\Bedaya\api\src\routes\index.ts
- E:\Work\Bedaya\api\src\index.ts
    requireStack: [
    'E:\\Work\\Bedaya\\api\\src\\models\\User.ts',
    'E:\\Work\\Bedaya\\api\\src\\controllers\\users.controller.ts',
    'E:\\Work\\Bedaya\\api\\src\\routes\\api\\users.route.ts',
    'E:\\Work\\Bedaya\\api\\src\\routes\\index.ts',
    'E:\\Work\\Bedaya\\api\\src\\index.ts'
  ]
```

Comment: You must also change `database` to `./database`. Modules without a leading `.` are packages that must have been installed with `npm`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `import routes from "./routes";` since it's a local file. Same with `./database` or any other local imports.